# Probabilistic coupling - definition and question

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, coupling

I am reading a paper and struggling with the concept of coupling. The paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.1404.pdf (page 14).

**Definition:**  If $Z_1:\Omega_1\to \mathbb{R}$ and $Z_2:\Omega_2\to \mathbb{R}$ are random variables on two probability spaces, then a coupling between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is a probability space $\Omega'$ together with two random variables $Z_1':\Omega'\to \mathbb{R}$ and $Z_2':\Omega'\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $Z_i'$ is distributed as $Z_i$.

**Question:** Suppose that $Z_1$ is such that $|Z_1|\le C$ almost surely, for some $C>0$. Can we couple in such a way that $|Z_1'|\le C$ almost surely?

The reason I ask this is that the argument appears a lot in proofs of the "almost sure invariance principle". Intuitively it seems like it should be true, but I am really struggling to write it in words to convince myself. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find a coupling between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, then the property you look for follows from the very definition: Since $Z_1'$ has the same distribution as $Z_1$, it will also have the same almost sure bound.

More precisely, $Z_1$ is a random variable on $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1, P_1)$ and $Z_1'$ is a random variable on some $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}', P')$ with

$$ P_1\circ Z_1^{-1}=P'\circ (Z_1')^{-1}.$$

In particular,

$$ P_1(|Z_1|\le C)=P'(|Z_1'|\le C),$$

so if either of these quantities is equal to $1$, then so is the other.

Comment: At the risk of a possibly silly question, is the measure on the left not supposed to be a product measure?

Comment: No, according to your definition, it doesn't have to be. But in general it's a different measure than the one on the right, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. In the linked paper, the author writes "by considering the distribution of $(Z_1',Z_2')\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$,  it follows that one may take WLOG $\Omega=E_1\times E_2$ and $Z_1'$ and $Z_2'$ to be the first and second projections respectively". So would it be correct to say WLOG your measure $P'$ is a product measure?

Comment: You're right, that's indeed what the author says by this. It does not follow from the definition, but you can assume it without loss of generality.